# I need help with an Alma Linux error with dnf: "There are no enabled repositories..."

Tags: dnf, alma-linux

I have a new install of Alma Linux 8 and I'm having a problem figuring out how to be able to install packages. When I run dnf, I get:

```
Error: There are no enabled repositories in "/etc/yum.repos.d", "/etc/yum/repos.d", "/etc/distro.repos.d".
```

my repolist:

```
repo id                                               repo name                                                           status
ha                                                    AlmaLinux 8 - HighAvailability                                      disabled
ha-debuginfo                                          AlmaLinux 8 - HighAvailability debuginfo                            disabled
ha-source                                             AlmaLinux 8 - HighAvailability Source                               disabled
plus                                                  AlmaLinux 8 - Plus                                                  disabled
plus-debuginfo                                        AlmaLinux 8 - Plus debuginfo                                        disabled
plus-source                                           AlmaLinux 8 - Plus Source                                           disabled
powertools                                            AlmaLinux 8 - PowerTools                                            disabled
powertools-debuginfo                                  AlmaLinux 8 - PowerTools debuginfo                                  disabled
powertools-source                                     AlmaLinux 8 - PowerTools Source                                     disabled
resilientstorage                                      AlmaLinux 8 - ResilientStorage                                      disabled
resilientstorage-debuginfo                            AlmaLinux 8 - ResilientStorage debuginfo                            disabled
resilientstorage-source                               AlmaLinux 8 - ResilientStorage Source                               disabled
```

One task I want to do is upgrade to PHP 8, but I need to get this dnf/repo issue figured out first.

I would be grateful for any guidance or links to references, as I haven't been able to quite find help regarding my particular situation.  Here's part of my hostnamectl output:

```
Virtualization: openvz
Operating System: AlmaLinux 8.5 (Arctic Sphynx)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:almalinux:almalinux:8::baseos
Kernel: Linux 4.18.0
Architecture: x86-64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux.repo` which is part of the [almalinux-release](http://mirror.steadfastnet.com/almalinux/8.5/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/almalinux-release-8.5-4.el8.x86_64.rpm) package. It has the “baseos”, “appstream”, etc. repositories defined in it.

I suggest reinstalling that package manually, and looking a lot closer at why your system is mysteriously missing a critical component like the base repos. Who else has super user on this system?